# Cant access file from http://192.168.1.2:8774/preseed/preseed.conf in Ubuntu cloud controller

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, eucalyptus

While installing node controller I receive this fatal error:

```
Failed to retrieve the preconfiguration file
The file needed for preconfiguration could not be retrieved from
http://192.168.1.2 :8774/preseed/preseed.conf. The installation will
proceed in non-automated mode.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you reinstall of CC?

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like you have either

1. Installation problem in the Cluster Controller, from the same Cluster Controller machine that you can telnet to the 8774 port at IP 192.168.1.2

   - Also check tha tIP 192.168.1.2 really belongs to the Cluster Controller, could be a misconfiguration
2. Network problem between the Node Controller and the Cluster Controller

   - Check that both are in the same network (not required but highly useful for small clusters)

In any case preseed is not really required for installing a node controller if you have direct console access to it somehow...

Answer (score 0):

edit IP info in /etc/networking/interfaces on Cloud Controller. Reboot controller. run ps -ef | grep avahi

If IP matches controller then try again on node cluster

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when doing a PXE boot of the Node Controller.

the problem arise when the Node Controller was synching in with the Cluster controller.

It seemed to be that the Cluster controller took over the TFTP session.

I installed the Node Controller from a CD, then it was no problem. We should report this bug (in my opinion) to Ubuntu....